# Downscale database dtu during out of office hours, it should happen every day automatically, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, terraform-provider-azure

I have multiple databases running in each environment which are charging me a lot of cost each month, so i wanted to downscale the DTUs to some lower count during non-working hours, again during working hours DTUs to be upscale back to actual DTUs count, it should happen automatically as per time settings every single day. If it's possible, can anyone please help me out with this?

I am trying write a terraform script and run the azure devops pipeline, deploy it in each subscription/environment as it automatically applies in each environment databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating [Azure Automation Account and use runbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/start-runbooks) to do the scheduled job. Using PowerShell/PowerShell Workflow as a runbook type would be better for this case. You can create 1 runbook for scale down and 1 for scale up.

You can use resource tags as your reference point for the target azure sql database/s. See link on [how to add tags a resource in Azure.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/tag-portal)
[image]

You can now use this tag as your parameter in your runbook script to view and make some changes on the target azure sql database.
Here is sample code snippet:

```
   workflow ScaleDown_DBs_S0_Tags
   {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $ScaleDown_Schedule_TagValue
        )

     InlineScript{
    
    $NewEdition = "Standard" 
    $NewTier = "S0" 

    #Converting Tag parameter for use in InlineScript
    $TagValue = $Using:ScaleDown_Schedule_TagValue
    
    #Getting the current subscription details
    $Context = Get-AzureRmContext

    #Getting the current subscription name
    $CurrentSub = $Context.Subscription.Name
    $Time = (get-date).ToString('T')
    Write-Output "Starting job at $($Time)"
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output "Getting all Databases with tags $($TagValue) under $($CurrentSub) Subscription..."
    
    #Getting all database objects with tags as per tag parameter
    $TaggedDBObjects = Get-AzureRmResource | where {$_.Tags.Values -like "*$TagValue*"}
    $count = $TaggedDBObjects.count 
    Write-Output "Total of $($Count) databases found:"
    $TaggedDBObjects.Name 
   
      foreach ($TaggedDBObject in $TaggedDBObjects) {
        $SplitName = $TaggedDBObject.Name.Split('/') 
        $SqlServerName = $SplitName[0]
        $DatabaseName = $SplitName[1] 
        $ResourceGroupName = $TaggedDBObject.ResourceGroupName 
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Output "Checking current Edition/Tier of $($DatabaseName)..."

        #Getting database complete object using Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase
        $GetDBs = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ServerName $SqlServerName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName
        $CurrentEdition = $GetDBs.Edition
        $CurrentTier = $GetDBs.CurrentServiceObjectiveName
        #Validating if Edition is already set and if action needed, if false
            if($CurrentTier -eq $NewTier){            
               
                Write-Output "Database $($DatabaseName) is already under $($CurrentEdition)/$($CurrentTier) plan. No action will be taken"
           
            }

            Else{
                Write-Output ""
                Write-Output "Current plan is $($CurrentEdition)/$($CurrentTier)"
                Write-Output ""
                Write-Output "Begin vertical scaling of database $($DatabaseName) to $($NewEdition)/$($NewTier) plan"
                Write-Output ""
                #Changing Edition/Tier accordingly
                Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -ServerName $SqlServerName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Edition $NewEdition -RequestedServiceObjectiveName $NewTier -AsJob
                
                Write-Output ""
                Write-Output "Database $($DatabaseName) successfully scaled to $($NewEdition)/$($NewTier)"
            
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

After working with the script, you can now [create a schedule and link it to your runbook.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runbooks#schedule-a-runbook-in-the-azure-portal)

[image]

Comment: Tried the run book and thrown multiple errors!

Comment: Hi @GowthamVarmaDanthuluri, I've update the script, I've miss to add the workflow part in the beginning can you try again on your end.